# Python Multiprocessing - Processes won't start?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Okay, so I have the following:

```
def sendernode(out_conn, matrix, vectors):
    print('sender started')
    #more code

def node(in_conn, out_conn, matrix, input_length):
    print('node started')
    #more code
```

Two kinds of nodes, that should process some vectors stored. `sendernode` should receive all the vectors in a list, multiply them by a matrix and send it via `out_conn`. Each subsequesnt `node` shall receive the vector after the matrix transformation via `in_conn`, perform another matrix transformation and send it to the next `node`. The main function does this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
#declarations and stuff

    processlist = []    
    results = []
    manager = Manager()    
    pipes = manager.list()

    print('Setting up pipelines...')
    for i in range(matrixnum+1):
        receiver, sender = Pipe(False)
        pipes.append([sender, receiver])    

    p = Process(target=sendernode, args=(pipes[0][0], matrices[0], vectors, ))
    processlist.append(p)

    for i in range(0,matrixnum-1):
        p = Process(target=node, args=(pipes[i][1], pipes[i+1][0], matrices[i+1], vectornum,))
        processlist.append(p)
```

It sets the processes up and stores them in `processlist`, assigns the correct pipes to use and the matrices to multiply with.

```
    for process in processlist:
        process.start()
```

And here's what's not working: Even though I start the processes, none of them seem to start, I don't get the messages they're supposed to `print` on the console. The rest of the main function is supposed to summarize the final results sent over the final pipe and wait for the processes to finish:

```
    keep_running = True
    i = 1
    while keep_running:
        if pipes[matrixnum][1].poll():
            end = pipes[matrixnum][1].recv()
            print('main received %i  (i=%i)' %(end[0],i ))
            i += 1
            results.append(end[:3])    
        if i == vectornum:
            keep_running = False    

    for process in processlist:
        process.join()
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is this not starting the processes? Thank you!

Comment: Strange, this seems to work for me. I simplified it a bit but it should not affect anything. Are none of the processes really started? If the sender starts but the nodes do not, then the only reason I can come up with is that `matrixnum` is actually 0. Also, how big should the `matrixnum` be? You do not want to start more processes than you have cores in your CPU.

Comment: It just hangs for me... `matrixnum` is 3 and I'm running it on a server with 20 cores...